# Why might this SIMD array-adding sample not be demonstrating any performance gains over a naive implementation?

Tags: c#, x86, simd, microbenchmark

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated ? "SIMD supported" : "SIMD not supported.");

        var rand = new Random();

        var numNums = 10000000;
        var arr1 = Enumerable.Repeat(0, numNums).Select(x => (int) (rand.NextDouble() * 100)).ToArray();
        var arr2 = Enumerable.Repeat(0, numNums).Select(x => (int) (rand.NextDouble() * 100)).ToArray();

        var simdResult = new int [numNums];
        var conventionalResult = new int [numNums];

        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        ConventionalArrayAddition(arr1, arr2, conventionalResult);
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Conventional time :" + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        var watch2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        SIMDArrayAddition(arr1, arr2, simdResult);
        watch2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Simd time :" + watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void SIMDArrayAddition(int[] lhs, int[] rhs, int [] result)
    {
        var simdLength = Vector<int>.Count;
        var i = 0;
        for (; i <= lhs.Length - simdLength; i += simdLength)
        {
            var va = new Vector<int>(lhs, i);
            var vb = new Vector<int>(rhs, i);
            (va + vb).CopyTo(result, i);
        }

        for (; i < lhs.Length; ++i)
        {
            result[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
        }
    }

    public static void ConventionalArrayAddition(int[] lhs, int[] rhs, int[] result)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lhs.Length; i ++)
        {
            result[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This code is adapted from one of the examples on https://instil.co/2016/03/21/parallelism-on-a-single-core-simd-with-c/.

I am compiling this as a .Net Framework console app (I've tried 4.6.1 and 4.7), with 'Optimize code' selected, as x64.

The results I get are along the lines of:

> Conventional time :22
>   Simd time :23

If I do a similar test in .net core, I do get faster results using the vector method, but only because the naïve implementation is much slower under .net core (taking about 55ms). The vectorised implementation in core is generally slightly slower (say, 24ms) than the results I get in .net framework.

My processor is an i5-7500T, and I have had similar results on an i5-7200.

Is there likely to be some other simple setting I'm neglecting? Or could it be that the compiler is somehow optimising to use simd instructions in the naïve code anyway?

UPDATE: following the instructions in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clrcodegeneration/2007/10/19/how-to-see-the-assembly-code-generated-by-the-jit-using-visual-studio/, Here is the disassembly for 
**ConventionalArrayAddition() :**

```
            for (int i = 0; i < lhs.Length; i++)
00000000  sub         rsp,28h 
00000004  xor         eax,eax 
00000006  mov         r9d,dword ptr [rcx+8] 
0000000a  test        r9d,r9d 
0000000d  jle         000000000000008A 
0000000f  test        rdx,rdx 
00000012  setne       r10b 
00000016  movzx       r10d,r10b 
0000001a  and         r10d,1 
0000001e  test        r8,r8 
00000021  setne       r11b 
00000025  movzx       r11d,r11b 
00000029  test        r11d,r10d 
0000002c  je          0000000000000066 
0000002e  cmp         dword ptr [rdx+8],r9d 
00000032  setge       r10b 
00000036  movzx       r10d,r10b 
0000003a  cmp         dword ptr [r8+8],r9d 
0000003e  setge       r11b 
00000042  movzx       r11d,r11b 
00000046  test        r11d,r10d 
00000049  je          0000000000000066 
            {
                result[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
0000004b  movsxd      r10,eax 
0000004e  mov         r11d,dword ptr [rcx+r10*4+10h] 
00000053  add         r11d,dword ptr [rdx+r10*4+10h] 
00000058  mov         dword ptr [r8+r10*4+10h],r11d 
            for (int i = 0; i < lhs.Length; i++)
0000005d  inc         eax 
0000005f  cmp         r9d,eax 
00000062  jg          000000000000004B 
00000064  jmp         000000000000008A 
00000066  movsxd      r10,eax 
00000069  mov         r11d,dword ptr [rcx+r10*4+10h] 
0000006e  cmp         eax,dword ptr [rdx+8] 
00000071  jae         000000000000008F 
00000073  add         r11d,dword ptr [rdx+r10*4+10h] 
00000078  cmp         eax,dword ptr [r8+8] 
0000007c  jae         000000000000008F 
0000007e  mov         dword ptr [r8+r10*4+10h],r11d 
00000083  inc         eax 
00000085  cmp         r9d,eax 
00000088  jg          0000000000000066 
0000008a  add         rsp,28h 
            }
        }
0000008e  ret 
0000008f  call        000000005FA91300 
00000094  int         3
```

and for **SIMDArrayAddition():**

```
    var simdLength = Vector<int>.Count;
00000000  push        rdi 
00000001  push        rsi 
00000002  sub         rsp,28h 
00000006  vzeroupper 
00000009  xor         eax,eax 
            for (; i <= lhs.Length - simdLength; i += simdLength)
0000000b  mov         r9d,dword ptr [rcx+8] 
0000000f  mov         r10d,r9d 
00000012  sub         r10d,8 
00000016  test        r10d,r10d 
00000019  jl          0000000000000064 
0000001b  mov         r11d,dword ptr [rdx+8] 
0000001f  mov         esi,dword ptr [r8+8] 
00000023  cmp         eax,r9d 
00000026  jae         00000000000000A2 
00000028  lea         edi,[rax+7] 
0000002b  cmp         edi,r9d 
0000002e  jae         00000000000000A2 
00000030  vmovupd     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rcx+rax*4+10h] 
                var vb = new Vector<int>(rhs, i);
00000037  cmp         eax,r11d 
0000003a  jae         00000000000000A2 
0000003c  cmp         edi,r11d 
0000003f  jae         00000000000000A2 
00000041  vmovupd     ymm1,ymmword ptr [rdx+rax*4+10h] 
                (va + vb).CopyTo(result, i);
00000048  vpaddd      ymm0,ymm0,ymm1 
0000004d  cmp         eax,esi 
0000004f  jae         00000000000000A7 
00000051  cmp         edi,esi 
00000053  jae         00000000000000AC 
00000055  vmovupd     ymmword ptr [r8+rax*4+10h],ymm0 
            for (; i <= lhs.Length - simdLength; i += simdLength)
0000005c  add         eax,8 
0000005f  cmp         r10d,eax 
00000062  jge         0000000000000023 
            }

            for (; i < lhs.Length; ++i)
00000064  cmp         r9d,eax 
00000067  jle         0000000000000098 
00000069  mov         r11d,dword ptr [rdx+8] 
0000006d  mov         esi,dword ptr [r8+8] 
            {
                result[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
00000071  cmp         eax,r9d 
00000074  jae         00000000000000A2 
00000076  movsxd      r10,eax 
00000079  mov         edi,dword ptr [rcx+r10*4+10h] 
0000007e  cmp         eax,r11d 
00000081  jae         00000000000000A2 
00000083  add         edi,dword ptr [rdx+r10*4+10h] 
00000088  cmp         eax,esi 
0000008a  jae         00000000000000A2 
0000008c  mov         dword ptr [r8+r10*4+10h],edi 
            for (; i < lhs.Length; ++i)
00000091  inc         eax 
00000093  cmp         r9d,eax 
00000096  jg          0000000000000071 
00000098  vzeroupper 
            }
        }
0000009b  add         rsp,28h 
0000009f  pop         rsi 
000000a0  pop         rdi 
000000a1  ret 
000000a2  call        000000005FA91250 
000000a7  call        000000005FA91B00 
000000ac  call        000000005FA91A50 
000000b1  int         3
```

These were obtained from a different machine (i7-4790), which is producing similar timings.

Comment: There are plenty of samples to be found for getting the actual assembly generated by the JIT. You could perhaps do that and add that code to your question?

Comment: In the code you have posted inside method `SIMDArrayAddition` you have both loops,` simd` and `conventional`.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria that's just for the very few leftover additions that don't fit in an exact number of multiples of the vector size (`i` is not reinitialised).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever updated.

Comment: Benchmark fail, you are not measuring what you think you are.  Measurements are dominated by jitting overhead, page fault costs to allocate RAM for the arrays and memory bus bandwidth.  Get rid of the first two by putting a loop around the test so it is repeated at least 10 times.  The memory bus is harder to get rid of, the arrays are too large to fit in the cpu caches so the program is bogged down by waiting for the slow RAM.  Change numNums to, say, 1000 and display Elapsed instead of ElapsedMilliseconds.  I see a ~40% speedup.

Comment: @HansPassant- the second assembly code code sample does include `vpaddd` instruction.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, rather than having such huge arrays, I tried adding tiny arrays (just 8 values) a large number of times. This showed about a 100% speedup.

Comment: If "100% speedup" means it was twice as fast then I saw a ~80% speedup.  No massive difference when I use 8, but do beware it gets to be awfully hard to reliably measure such very fast code.  Your processor is 4 years younger than mine (I've got Haswell) so comparing is a bit iffy.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm fairly new to optimisation techniques so I don't have a good feel of what the relative speeds of things are, where the overheads might be etc. I think your comment represents the learning point I needed, thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant oddly, if I run the .exe directly from \bin\Release, the 'optimised' version is about twice as *slow*... is that the same for you? (if you still have the code handy)

Comment: No, it is fine.  I have no handy theory for that one.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the implementation to `AddTo` to reduce the number of sources and destinations, improves performance by about 70%. This addition is useful in many cases, and how most CPU internal additions work, reducing memory bandwidth and cache requirements.

```
    public static void SIMDArrayAddTo(int[] lhs, int[] rhs)
    {
        var simdLength = Vector<int>.Count;
        var end = lhs.Length - simdLength;
        var i = 0;
        for (; i <= end; i += simdLength)
        {
            var va = new Vector<int>(lhs, i);
            var vb = new Vector<int>(rhs, i);
            (va + vb).CopyTo(lhs, i);
        }

        for (; i < lhs.Length; ++i)
        {
            lhs[i] += rhs[i];
        }
    }
```

I also tried unrolling the SSE loop, but it didn't seem to help. Added version similar to this one to the HPCsharp nuget package, including a multi-core version.

Also, added multi-core paralelism on top of the above function, which didn't improve performance. If anyone has access to a CPU with more than 2 memory channels, it would be interesting to see how this code scales when more system memory bandwidth is available.

Comment: related: On current dual/quad-core Intel CPUs, a single core can nearly saturate memory bandwidth.  On many-core Xeon CPUs, single-core bandwidth is *lower* (higher latency to L3 and DRAM limits bandwidth for the same max-concurrency of outstanding cache misses), as well as aggregate bandwidth being higher.  [Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39260020).  So yes it does take multiple cores to saturate memory bandwidth on a CPU with more cores.