# Is there a faster way to add arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, addition

I am trying optimize for speed. I just want to add values from one array into another array.

This is iterating over the pixels in an image so it only takes about small time even for a big image. The problem is when I animate the image this becomes significant.

I started with a simple for loop.
A parallel loop was faster.
A parallel loop with a nested for loop was faster.

I still feel like there should be something that exploits the low-level CPU instructions the way memcopy does. Adding arrays seems like something that would be in the instruction set.

The code below is where I am ATM.

```
            Parallel.For(0, size.Width, (i) => {
                int from = i * size.Height;
                int to = from + size.Height;
                for (int j = from; j < to; j++) data[j] += map.Data[j]; }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding arrays seems like something that would be in the instruction set

It is, it is in general called SIMD and for x86/x64 it is SSE (for ARM, you have NEON, for PowerPC, AltiVec, and so on).

There's no language support in C#, but some JIT compilers (Mono.Simd, RyuJIT) have special-cased support for converting calls to certain library functions into the SSE instructions.

See

- [First support in Mono](https://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-03.html)
- [Modern support in Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/news/2016/12/20/system-numeric-vectors/)
- [First support in .NET Framework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-jit-finally-proposed-jit-and-simd-are-getting-married/)
- [Current support in .NET Framework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-ryujit-transition-is-complete/)

Answer (score 0):

C# supports SIMD/SSE CPU instructions in System.Numerics. Addition is an operation that benefits from SIMD/SSE instructions and multi-core up to the limit of system memory bandwidth. Take a look at a similar stackoverflow question
[Why might this SIMD array-adding sample not be demonstrating any performance gains over a naive implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553540/why-might-this-simd-array-adding-sample-not-be-demonstrating-any-performance-gai/57032048#57032048)

Another resource is the HPCsharp nuget package on nuget.org, which I maintain, take a look at AddParallel.cs implementation of AddToSse().